# Siunitx - keep leading zeroes while parse-numbers=true

Tags: siunitx

The default suggestion for keeping leading zeros is to set `parse-numbers=false`.

However, I have a lot of examples where the decimal markers varies between , and . Thus, I need the parser to change the to correct `output-decimal-marker` which I sometimes set to "," for Norwegian documents and sometimes to "." for English documents.

Is it possible to retain leading zeros for typesetting e.g.

`\num{0000.0001}` to produce `0000.0001` rather than `0.0001`

and

`\num{01.0001}` to produce `01.0001` rather than `1.0001`
without turning off the parser?

My setup currently is

```
\sisetup{
    propagate-math-font=true,
    group-digits=false,
    table-figures-decimal=0,
    table-number-alignment=center,
    input-digits={0123456789ABCDEF},
    %parse-numbers = false,
    detect-all=true,
    input-exponent-markers={},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}
```

Update! Answer is accepted although it is not a solution. I got my wish for the author to consider adding this to the siunitx-package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `minimum-integer-digits`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits = 4}
\begin{document}
\num{000.0001}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For my initial example that is ok. But I have updated my question. The number of decimal-digits may vary... I have created a `\dnum[]{}`
 where I can specify the number of integer-digits, but is quite daunting when you are trying to typeset several hundred numbers in a similar manner.

Comment: @DrJay Non-significant digits are dropped during parsing, which is why the option is about _minimum_ digits. Retaining non-significant digits would be a feature request: I'd need a clear justification and link to the published literature.

Comment: Sure! Didn't cross my mind. This is used when typesetting binary numbers. The number of digits are important. I am a text-book author and have started on a new example-book in Digital Design/Boolean algebra/Digital Electronics. M. Morris Mano's book "Digital Design" is a classic example where this is used.

Comment: https://www.pearson.com/en-gb/subject-catalog/p/digital-design-global-edition/P200000004916/9781292456423

Comment: @DrJay Stuff you've published yourself doesn't count ;) More seriously, this is borderline for scope for `siunitx`, which is about physical units, etc., and even if you represent them as binary, the leading non-significant zeros are still ... non-significant. That said, it's not hard to add an option for this, other than perhaps it might bite me in some rounding/display code - I'll think about it.

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/706 so it doesn't get lost

Comment: Well as I am not Morris Mano... ;-)

Comment: @DrJay No, I meant the bit where you said you were writing something; I'd perhaps still be cautious, as books might be typeset by the authors themselves - journals tend to be a better bet as they are typeset by specialists.

Comment: I get your point Joseph. I do typeset my own books. The only motivation is to reduce the cost for my students. I do also reuse material between books, exams, tutorials and exercises. And I also try write duplicates in English and in Norwegian. But I also understand that it might be a bit narrow request.

Answer (score 2):

As a stop gap, you could define a custom macro that automatically adds `minimum-integer-digits` based on your input number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    propagate-math-font=true,
    group-digits=none,
    input-digits={0123456789ABCDEF},
    detect-all=true,
    input-exponent-markers={},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \drjay_gobble_decimals:w #1 . #2 \q_stop {#1}
\cs_new:Npn \drjay_integer_digits:n #1
  { \tl_count:o { \drjay_gobble_decimals:w #1 .\q_stop } }
\NewDocumentCommand\numretained{O{} m}
  {%
    \use:e
      {
        \exp_not:N \num
          [
            minimum-integer-digits =  \drjay_integer_digits:n {#2},
            \exp_not:n {#1}
          ]
      }
      {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\numretained{000.0001}

\numretained{01.0001}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanx! I actually went on doing just that. Even made separate ones for hex, oct, bin and deci numbers with optional arguments. However, your syntax is so much better than mine. I'll adapt it. And I gotta love the use of my username ;-)

Comment: @DrJay that's because in the used coding layer (L3, or `expl3`) one should always use a module name, and since that's an adhoc module it is quite customary (around here) to use the user name of the OP (you could as well replace every `drjay` with `my`).